None permissible names of ALLAH for a child without ABDUL? Please kindly help me out
Assalamualaikum,
We named our son Kabeer (one of Allah’s names) before naming him, we did our long research and named him without ABDUL. Now we’re hearing from different people, we have to add ABDUL before his name since it’s Allah’s name. As far as my knowledge, their are 7 names of ALLAH, we have to have add ABDUL and his name is not one of them. Please help us out do we have to add ABDUL or my son name doesn’t required ABDUL.
Thank you so much,

"Al-Kabeer" (The Great) is one of the names of Allah. "Kabeer" (great) is a general adjective that's not unique to Allah, and should be fine as a name. See the linked duplicate for further details.
